# asp.net tooltip appears very big for the text inside

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, css

I am trying to use the asp.net tooltip property to display the text in case if there is over flow. but the tool tip appears to be almost 300px wide and almost 100px high. but the text is a few characters.. So I want to know what can cause this behaviour. As there is no extra setting for this property.

```
      <div style="clear: both; overflow:hidden;">
      <asp:Label ID="LabelSubject" runat="server" BackColor="" Font-Size="Small" CssClass="overflowmanagement"  style="max-width:230px; float:left; border:1px solid #ccc; border-bottom:1px solid #fff; border-top-right-radius:4px; font-weight:bold;"></asp:Label>
      </div>
```

css

```
       .overflowmanagement
    {
        text-overflow:ellipsis;
        overflow:hidden;
        display:block;
        white-space:nowrap ;
        }
```

asp.net

```
           LabelSubject.ToolTip = LabelSubject.Text;
```

Comment: in the absense of any code/html/css or screen shots to review... I'm going to guess that it was caused by a wizard riding a unicorn. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: lol... I know how to ask but I have a label and I set the the tooltip property for it so I did not feel necessary to past a label control with very much standard form..  your comment is to harsh.. :(

Comment: show your asp/html... that comment is the first time that you even mentioned the word `label`.

Comment: I have updated the question ... check it

Answer (score 0):

Is there something overiding the settings of your tooltip? Or If you are creating it dynamically, or reusing it there may be some old settings that you didn't deal with. It's a mistake that I frequently make.

Comment: What can override the settings of tooltip.. I am trying to get to the tooltip to check the generated html but it dispears when i try to hover over it. I can't guess what can affect it.

Comment: My first suggestion would usually be to see if your tooltip is inheriting any other css classes. If something has been changed in the default CSS class that the tooltip inherits from, and is not mentioned in your overflowmanagement css class your tooltip might default to the settings specified in the original class. Is it inheriting from CSS that is being used elsewhere?